# css modification to allow images to display better on mobile

Tags: css

Ok so here is my problem - I am using bootstrap responsive and everything is great until a user goes on a small tablet or phone - they images then are too small - following the .box css of 214 px - I want the images to fill the screen space when a user views on phone but still look the same on a desktop..any ideas?

My CSS File:

```
$navbarBackgroundHighlight: white;
$navbarBackground: white;
$btnPrimaryBackground: green;

@import 'bootstrap';
body{
    padding-top: 60px;
}

body{
    padding-left: 60px;
}




@import 'bootstrap-responsive';





.footer{
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: $grayLight;
    a{
        color: $gray;
    }
}

/* Required for jQuery Masonry */

.box {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    float: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #444;
    width: 214px;

}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.description {
    margin: 10px 0 5px;
}


#tag_cloud {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  .s { font-size: 0.9em; color: #3B52A3 ;font-weight: italic; font-family: inherit }
  .ss { font-size: 1.2em; color: #118C4E ;font-weight: bold; font-family: inherit }
  .m { font-size: 1.8em; color: #005A31; font-weight: italic; font-family: inherit }
  .mm { font-size: 2.4em; color: #CE3927; font-weight: bold; font-family: inherit }
  .l { font-size: 3.0em; color: #B71427; font-weight: bold; font-family: inherit }
  .ll { font-size: 3.7em; color: #AECC23; font-weight: bold; font-family: inherit }

}

.hero-unit {
  background-image:url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/barnpix/pins/images/000/000/087/original/DSC00071.JPG?1375385330');
  background-size:cover;
  color: white;
  a:hover {
     color: #ABC147;
     text-decoration: underline;
}
  height:auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

and my view:

```
<%= render 'pages/home' %>



<div id="pins">
  <%= render @pins %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @pins %>
```

Comment: can you use the developer tool on your browser to display all css being applied to your image ?

Comment: I am not sure how this well help me though?

Comment: i am looking at the css you posted it seems Ok for the effect you are looking for, except that i am not sure of the version of boostrap you are using. I think i have an answer

Comment: ok great - yea basically I like how everything is looking except for the face that the images are only 214px so when the sreeen size is smaller the 214 image actually doesnt fill the screen

Comment: I am using :   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.1'

Comment: I figured it out:


    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .box {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

This modifies the css of .box to be 100% and fill the screen if the resolution is below 400px :)

Comment: yes the fixe is described in version 3 : max-width:0; :) my guess